# Second container not adjusting to full height of the first container in React app

Tags: css, reactjs

I have two containers in my app. One of them is a `ReactPrismEditor` and the other one is just a container with some text displayed.

When there is a lot of text inside the first container, `ReactPrismEditor`, it gets expanded downward, but I cannot get my second container to adjust to the height of the first one:

[image]

So the starting point is that they are all set to 100vh, but if the first one is more than 100vh, the other one should adjust.

Here is what I have:

```
  return (
    <AppContainer>
      <FirstContainer>
        <ReactPrismEditor
          ...
        />
      </FirstContainer>

      <SecondContainer>
...
      </SecondContainer>
    </AppContainer>
);
```

and my css:

```
const FirstContainer = styled.div`
width: 50%;
height: 100vh;
`

const SecondContainer = styled.div`
width: 50%;
height: 100vh;
`

const AppContainer = styled.div`
display: flex;
width: 100vw;
background:#272822;
`
```

I have tried the following:

- set `{ height: 100%; }` for SecondContainer,
- set `{ height: auto; }` for SecondContainer,
- set `{ position: relative; min-height: 100vh; height: 100%; }` for SecondContainer
- set `{ position: sticky; }` for SecondContainer

None of those worked.
I would be grateful for any hints on how to solve this.

I am not able to paste the code into the code snippet editor (it's not working).

Inspect on the white area:

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

I have been able to put my code into a code sandbox.
Due to lack of support, I cannot include the prism editor in there, thus the first column is also not stretching correctly - but maybe this will be at least a bit helpful in therm of troubleshooting to see the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-cherry-7titw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you inspect and see what kind of space filling that area, is it margin or padding? if you can't maybe paste your code somewhere like codepen

Comment: It's pointing to the `<html>` tag when I inspect - I'll update my question with a screenshot.

Comment: Sadly thats not enough for me to figure out the real problem if you can upload your code on codepen or snack or anywhere it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if something like this can help:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-lake-mc0j3?file=/src/App.js

I have only added a `align-item: stretch` to the `AppContainer` and removed the `height` in the `FirstContainer` and the `SecondContainer`

**Edit with the sticky issue:**

Here you can check the result:

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-shaw-5sw78?file=/src/App.js

I have only added a new `ThirdItem` (the name is arbitrary) to include the sticky property:

```
const ThirdItem = styled.div`
  padding: 20px;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
`;
```

I have also change the padding property from `ThirdContainer` to keep the text still when scrolling. I hope this helps.

Comment: Halleluja! That did it - thanks! If I can ask a follow-up question - I would like the last container `ThirdContainer` to stay in place the whole time - so something like `position: sticky;` but that doesn't work - any ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: It says I need to wait 20 hours until I can award the bounty

Comment: Ok, don't worry. I edited the answer to include the sticky problem.

Comment: Thanks - just had a look but now the third container acts just like the second one - it scrolls with the rest. I was wondering if it would be possible that it just stays at 100vh and doesn't scroll, so that the `bla bla bla` in the last container is always visible and in the same place?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't fork the first link while editing. Check the second one

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't work in your case then it might be due to the way ReactPrismEditor re-renders after the AppContainer has mounted.

Easiest fix would be to set the background color on AppContainer instead. If you have multiple columns you can give the AppContainer a stripped background.

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, 
     red 50%, green 50% 75%, yellow 75% 100%);
}
```

This is a bit of a hack solution and doesnt work great if you want lots of styling. to hack border lines.

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, 
     red 50%, green 50% 74.5%, black 74.5% 75%, yellow 75% 100%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but unfortunately, it didn't work. Maybe it's because it's a React? I have no idea...

Comment: i just updated my answer to use height: inherit; does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately `min-height: inherit;` also doesn't work

Comment: I think the secondContainers size is being set on mount but is then not updated when the the firstContainer re-renders.
do you have much styling on the second container? if you give the AppContainer the background color instead of the secondContainer. For appearances it wouldn't notice.

Comment: I will be adding a third container in a different colour later, so that approach won't work - but thanks for the workaround. If the second container's size is set on mount, why doesn't position; sticky work in that case? That would also be an acceptable solution for me

Comment: Position sticky may not work correctly if any parent element has a set height and its not supported by all browsers. I've re-written my answer using position absolute to see if that works instead? I'm not super knowledgeable on how the React DOM works but it looks like the SecondContainer is on a different Node to the first so doesnt re-render when the first does.

Comment: adding `position: absolute;` to first container and `position: relative;` to the second one just messed everything up - now the second container is on top of the first one, but still, it's height is only 100vh

Comment: hmm, i've re-worked my answer (again) to allow for multiple columns. Still is a bit of a hack though.

Comment: I've added my code to a code sandbox, link in the OP